# Uninstalling Google Update

Tags: windows, google-chrome, uninstall, google-updates

So, I installed Google Chrome a while back to test it, but I'm still too attached to Firefox to let go. Today I uninstalled Chrome, but I see Google Update spread all around my PC. There's a Firefox plugin, a task to run on startup, a task on task scheduler, and who knows what else.

How can I completely uninstall any traces of Google from my machine? If there's no simple method, does any know where else in Windows it gets installed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [here](http://www.google.com/support/pack/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=53402) and from [here](http://www.google.com/support/installer/bin/answer.py?answer=98805)

There is 2 different things are avilable in google upate(r)

**Google Updater** is installed when you download Google Pack or Google Earth. It may also come pre-installed with other Google software on your computer. The Updater provides an easy interface to help you manage Google Earth and other software available through Google Pack. When Google Updater is running, you'll see the process GoogleUpdater.exe in Task Manager.

**Google Update** is an open source component of several different Google programs, including Google Chrome and Google Earth. It helps keeps these programs up-to-date. When Google Update is running, you won't see any new windows but may notice the process GoogleUpdate.exe in Task Manager. Google Update is also known as Omaha, which is the name for the open-source project.

***Uninstall Google Update***

Google Update can't be removed by itself. If you remove Google Update processes from your computer, you may find that your Google programs no long function properly and, in many cases, you may see Google Update return automatically.

To fully uninstall Google Update, uninstall any Google applications you currently have installed. Immediately after uninstalling your other Google programs, Google Update should be uninstalled automatically.

***Uninstall Google Updater***

If you'd like to uninstall the Google Updater, click the link for one of the methods below:

Uninstall from the Start Menu

1. Go to the Start menu > Programs > Google Updater > Uninstall Google Updater.
2. Restart your computer after you uninstall.

Uninstall from the Control Panel

1. Click the Start menu on your computer taskbar.
2. Select Control Panel.
3. Double-click Add or Remove Programs (on XP) or Programs and Features (on Vista).
4. Select Google Updater in the list of programs.
5. Click Remove.
6. Restart your computer after you uninstall.

Uninstall from the command line (advanced)

1. Click the Start menu on your computer taskbar.
2. Select Run.
3. Enter cmd to open a command prompt.
4. Type cd C:\Program Files\Google\Google Updater to change directories.
5. Type GoogleUpdater.exe -uninstall to uninstall.
6. Restart your computer after you uninstall.

Comment: I used to have google earth installed, but it's long gone now. And looking into "control panel" or the "program files" folder I can't find any google applications currently installed (not even google updater or google update). Does that mean the traces I found were simply leftovers and don't really link to anything?

Comment: "googleupdate -uninstall" is the only thing that worked

Comment: Sometimes a chrome install will hang if googleupdate is already there.

Comment: For "googleupdate -uninstall" to work, all google products must be uninstalled first, like chrome and earth.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that once you have uninstalled all Google software the Google updater will uninstall itself after about a day.  But if you have any Google programs installed then uninstalling the updater may break them.

Answer (score 0):

After uninstalling the Google hangouts plugin, I noticed Google update was still in my Firefox plugins.
Both programs were installed without Administrator privilege, to uninstall Google update for Firefox execute these simples steps.

Delete this folder C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google
Delete all the Google update tasks in Windows Task Scheduler.

After completing this you should no longer see Google update plugin on the Firefox plugin page.

*Note: These steps are to uninstall the Google update plugin for Firefox.*

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with `GoogleUpdate.exe` deleting all `.bat` files in `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local`

This virus is actualy several bat files calling each other located in the Local folder.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found that there was a service running named chromeupdater.exe
To fix it, I first, stopped that service and then I deleted it from the below location:

> C:\Windows\servicing

Answer (score 0):

Running this task in task scheduler seems to uninstall google update, if no other google products are installed, like chrome and earth.  Otherwise it runs once a day.  What are all  the command line options?  Maybe this:  https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/omaha/+/7274410f62ef28144a49ac54e315f037f5e01b96/common/const_cmd_line.h

```
\GoogleUpdateTaskMachineUA

Action:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Update\GoogleUpdate.exe /ua /installsource scheduler

Trigger:
Daily at a random time
```

Google update may get into an unstable state where updates no longer work, for example going from a newer 32-bit chrome to an older 64-bit chrome.  It will fail halfway through and remove the package information, but not the application itself.  It may require manually removing google update.  It is not registered in add/remove programs.  It is always 32-bit.

Group policy for google update and also how to make a google update log file:  https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6350036?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Use `msiexec`:

```
msiexec /x "{60EC980A-BDA2-4CB6-A427-B07A5498B4CA}"
```